# want to post my edit text message to facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook

i have a activity which contains an edit text and one button for sharing this edit text message to facebook . but my edit text message is not passing through the facebook wall.i have integrated the facebook sdk. anyone please help me

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
           import android.widget.Toast;

         import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
         import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
          import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
             import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

public class FacebookpostScreen extends Activity{

    private static final String APP_ID = "myappid";
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream"};

    private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
        private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
        private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";

    private Facebook facebook;
    private String messageToPost;

    public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
            return editor.commit();
        }

        public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
            facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
            return facebook.isSessionValid();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        restoreCredentials(facebook);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.facebookpostscreen);

        String facebookMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("filteredMessage");
        if (facebookMessage == null){
            facebookMessage = "Test wall post";
        }
        messageToPost = facebookMessage;
    }

    public void doNotShare(View button){
        finish();
    }
    public void share(View button){
        if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            loginAndPostToWall();
        }
        else {
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
    }

    public void loginAndPostToWall(){
         facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
    }

    public void postToWall(String message){
        Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
        try {
               String response = facebook.request("me");
               Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
               parameters.putString("message", message);
               parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
               response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                       "POST");
               Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
               if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                       response.equals("false")) {
                  Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
            }
            else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            }
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }

    class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            saveCredentials(facebook);
            if (messageToPost != null){
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
        }
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
            finish();
        }
        public void onCancel() {
            showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you recevie in your OnFacebookeError() or onError() methods ?

Comment: it is opening the share activity of facebook with blank message. actually my application message is not passing to facebook post

Comment: You don't pass the message to dialog. You must find out name of url paramter using to pass the message text, Then you should create Bundle with this parameter and pass it to dialog() method

Answer (score 0):

Please check this option
Might be it can help u ... !!!

```
private void updateStatus() {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            String _statusMessage = EDT_STATUS_MSG.getText().toString();//ur edit text value

            Log.i(TAG, _statusMessage);
            if (session != null) {

                      Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
                postParams.putString("message", _statusMessage);// the status message to wall
                Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                        String postId = null;
                        try {
                            postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                        if (error != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Post Id of status msg = " + postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                };

                Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

                RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                task.execute();
            }
        }
```